# Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can't make field constructor accessible

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2, activeandroid, gson

I am having problem with ActiveAndroid while saving data.

```
import com.activeandroid.Model;
import com.activeandroid.annotation.Column;
import com.activeandroid.annotation.Table;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Table(name = "login_response")
public class LoginResponse extends Model{
    @Column(name = "a_token")
    @SerializedName("access_token")
    public String mAccessToken;

    @Column(name = "expiry_time")
    @SerializedName("expires_in")
    public Long mExpiresIn;

    @Column(name = "refresh_token")
    @SerializedName("refresh_token")
    public String mRefreshToken;


    @Column(name = "scope")
    @SerializedName("scope")
    public String mScope;

    @Column(name = "token_type")
    @SerializedName("token_type")
    public String mTokenType;

    public LoginResponse(){}

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return mAccessToken;
    }

    public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        mAccessToken = accessToken;
    }

    public Long getExpiresIn() {
        return mExpiresIn;
    }

    public void setExpiresIn(Long expiresIn) {
        mExpiresIn = expiresIn;
    }

    public String getRefreshToken() {
        return mRefreshToken;
    }

    public void setRefreshToken(String refreshToken) {
        mRefreshToken = refreshToken;
    }

    public String getScope() {
        return mScope;
    }

    public void setScope(String scope) {
        mScope = scope;
    }

    public String getTokenType() {
        return mTokenType;
    }

    public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
        mTokenType = tokenType;
    }
}
```

The above is the Mapping class for response obtained using retrofit while fetching data from web api.
But I got and error like this.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    Process: com.bidhee.onlinepayment, PID: 3826
>                                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for
>   class com.bidhee.onlinepayment.model.login.LoginResponse
>                                                        for method LoginApi.getResponse
>                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:695)
>                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createResponseConverter(ServiceMethod.java:681)
>                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:166)
>                                                        at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
>                                                        at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
>                                                        at $Proxy2.getResponse(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at com.bidhee.onlinepayment.ui.viewpresenter.login.LoginPresenterImpl.attemptLogin(LoginPresenterImpl.java:39)
>                                                        at com.bidhee.onlinepayment.ui.viewpresenter.login.LoginRegisterActivity.onBtnSignInClicked(LoginRegisterActivity.java:93)
>                                                        at com.bidhee.onlinepayment.ui.viewpresenter.login.LoginRegisterActivity$$ViewBinder$1.doClick(LoginRegisterActivity$$ViewBinder.java:23)
>                                                        at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)
>                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can't make field constructor accessible
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:334)
>                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.newDefaultConstructor(ConstructorConstructor.java:101)
>                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.get(ConstructorConstructor.java:83)
>                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:95)
>                                                        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:416)
>                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory.getKeyAdapter(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:140)
>                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory.create(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
>                                                        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:416)
>                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:135)
>                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:105)
>                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:104)
>                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160)
>                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
>                                                        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:416)
>                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:135)
>                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:105)
>                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:104)
>                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160)
>                                                        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
>                                                        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:416)
>                                                        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory.responseBodyConverter(GsonConverterFactory.java:63)
>                                                        at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:325)
>                                                        at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:308)
>                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createResponseConverter(ServiceMethod.java:679)
>                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:166) 
>                                                        at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166) 
>                                                        at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393) 
>                                                        at $Proxy2.getResponse(Unknown Source) 
>                                                        at com.bidhee.onlinepayment.ui.viewpresenter.login.LoginPresenterImpl.attemptLogin(LoginPresenterImpl.java:39) 
>                                                        at com.bidhee.onlinepayment.ui.viewpresenter.login.LoginRegisterActivity.onBtnSignInClicked(LoginRegisterActivity.java:93) 
>                                                        at com.bidhee.onlinepayment.ui.viewpresenter.login.LoginRegisterActivity$$ViewBinder$1.doClick(LoginRegisterActivity$$ViewBinder.java:23) 
>                                                        at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22) 
>                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
>                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

It was working fine before ActiveAndroid But when I am trying to use Active android I got the above errors.
I can same the manually created object of different class and save it but while using retrofit and active android I can't.

I am using retrofit with the dependencies

**compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'**

**compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'**

This is how I am building the retrofit client

```
okhttpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        retrofitBuilder = new Retrofit.Builder();

        client = okhttpClientBuilder
                .addInterceptor(new ApiInterceptor())
                .build();

        retrofit = retrofitBuilder
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
```

**The way I am calling the api is**

```
Retrofit retrofit = OnlinePaymentApplication.getRetrofit();
        APIs.LoginApi api = retrofit.create(APIs.LoginApi.class);
        Call<LoginResponse> call = api.getResponse(grantType, clientId, clientSecret, userName, userPassword);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                loginView.hideProgress();

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    loginView.onLoginDataReceived(response.body());
                } else {
                    ErrorResponse error = ErrorUtils.parseError(response);
                    loginView.onErrorMessageReceived(error.getMessage());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                loginView.hideProgress();

                if (t instanceof IOException) {
                    loginView.onErrorMessageReceived(MetaData.NETWORK_ERROR);
                } else {
                    loginView.onErrorMessageReceived(t.getLocalizedMessage());
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: add where you call it

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify that you wants a Gson converter with version `2.0.0` like this :

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```